# R plotly barplot, sort by value

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly

I have a barplot with categories on X axis and counts on Y. Is there a way to sort the bars in descending order on values of Y?

this is the sample code

```
Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
Count <- c(20, 14, 23)
data <- data.frame(Animals, Count)

data <- arrange(data,desc(Count))

plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~Count, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo')
```

Despite of arranging the data by count before the plot, I still get bars sorted alphabetically by animal names.

thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A couple things:

1. Look at `str(data)`, your `Animals` character vector is coerced to a factor unless you specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your call to `data.frame`. The levels of this factor are alphabetic by default.
2. Even if `Animals` is made to be a character vector in `data`, `plot_ly` doesn't know what to do with character variables and so will coerce them to factors.

**You need to set factor level order to get the descending order you are looking for.**

```
Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
Count <- c(20, 14, 23)
data <- data.frame(Animals, Count, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data$Animals <- factor(data$Animals, levels = unique(data$Animals)[order(data$Count, decreasing = TRUE)])
plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~Count, type = "bar", name = 'SF Zoo')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I did try using tab <- arrange(tab,desc(n)) before the plot but it did not work. I also specified sort = FALSE within plotly to make sure that it doesn't resort but still does not work.

Comment: If `tab$Category` is a factor, then `plot_ly` will use the level order as the order in which to display the plot. You'll need to reorder the levels of `tab$Category` given `tab$Count`. You may find the `stats::reorder` function helpful: `tab$Category <- reorder(x = tab$Category, X = tab$Count, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Hi Jeff, my Categories are not factors and the table is getting sorted correctly before the plot. However, plot_ly sorts my categories alphabetically while generating the plot. 

It is happening exactly like the example below where animals are displayed alphabetically in the chart despite of the order specified below

plot_ly(
  x = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  y = c(20, 14, 23),
  name = "SF Zoo",
  type = "bar"
)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: is there a tidyverse friendly version of this answer? would be great to use this within one statement before generating a `plot_ly` object... as noted above, even if `arrange(desc(Count))` is used as the previous statement, it doesn't work

Answer (score 13):

to sort the bars descending by their value, you need to use a layout attribute of xaxis like so:

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~Animals, y = ~Count, type = 'bar', name = 'SF Zoo') %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(categoryorder = "total descending"))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It worked out-of-the-box without any data manipulation. Thanks phillyooo.